# SharePoint 2010 site template designer workflows limitation

Tags: designer-workflow, site-template

I have a SharePoint 2010 site with 5 lists which have designer workflows associated with them. I am trying to create template out of the site and make use of the lists all over my application. But I am unable to get the workflows along with the template. Is this the limitation of SharePoint 2010 or am I missing something here.If it is not possible what would be the best solution in my case as we need this template to create more than 150 and more sites in our application in mere future.

If SharePoint doesn't allow this why does the template won't carry workflows when it mentions all the content can be carried and so?

Comment: As per this article, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-a-SharePoint-site-as-a-template-5a4eb024-d1fa-4681-a4ac-e6bd1e3209ba#__toc247465693
It is said that site template will take backup of workflows too, are you missing something.?

Comment: HI karthik it was strange that when I tried none of the workflows have came through but I just tested in my test environment and it is working fine but in prod it is not. Is there any feature or setting I have to do before I create a template?

Comment: are you trying to save as template from SharePoint designer or from Site Collection UI

Comment: hi waqas its from Site Collection UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflows will be copied but you need to make them run manually.

This article will help you to understand what site template contains.

[SharePoint 2010 “Save as template” (what is saved, what is not saved)](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/sharepoint-2010-save-as-template-what-is-saved-what-is-not-saved/)

Comment: I was able to get the workflow in template without running them manually. It is working in dev environment but not in my prod. Is there any setting I have to do before I make a template?